# How to Change Column Data from String to Float in My Code

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am running this code in d3 to sort a column in a table.

```
var upSort = thead.selectAll("th")        
    .on("click", (function(d,i) {
        d3.select(this).attr("id", "hello"),
        rows.sort(function(a, b) {
            return d3.ascending(a[i], b[i]);
        })
    }));
```

I have many problems but the immediate one is that column 0 is a string not a float and I can't figure out how or where to turn it in a float. I know that I need to use parseInt or +.

I load all the date like so:

```
d3.text("data.tsv",      
        function(dataset){

            var data = d3.tsv.parseRows(dataset);

            var table = d3.select("body")
                .append("table"),
            thead = table.append("thead"),
            tbody = table.append("tbody");

            a = data.shift();

            var header = d3.select("thead").selectAll("th")
                .data(a)
                .enter()
                .append("th")
                .style("border", "1px black solid")
                .style("padding", "5px")
                .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

Could or should I change it here?

Comment: Perhaps [parseFloat](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.3)?

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseFloat`

```
    rows.sort(function(a, b) {
        return d3.ascending(parseFloat(a[i]), parseFloat(b[i]));
    })
```

Comment: Thank you! Couldn't figure out where it should go.